# Using EF6 migrations and changing datatype to DATE

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, sqldatatypes

Our initial migration added a column with a sql DATETIMEOFFSET datatype. However we now want to change the sql datatype to DATE, as no time information is stored.

How can we do this with EF migrations? .Net obviously only has DateTime and DateTimeOffset datatypes.

I know we could use the DbModelBuilder and the HasColumnType("date") method on the entity, but surely that would apply to all migrations, not just the latest (and all subsequent migrations).

Cheers

Comment: Is there a reason you are reluctant to simply use the generic `Sql(sql)` method instead and implement the mechanics of this migration yourself?  (sometimes that's the best you can do with more sophisticated migrations)

Comment: Yea, tbh I'm a bit green with ef migrations, but I did see there was a Sql method. Was just hoping there would be a more strongly typed solution.

Comment: little about migrations is "strongly typed".  There are simply those migrations that can be generated for you, and those that can't.  Either way, the migrations contain a whole bunch of strings.

Comment: True. We also use roundhouse, which is obviously all sql statements, so was just trying to use the migration helper methods as much as possible, otherwise i may as well continue using roundhouse :) but using the Sql() method occasionally is fine by me

Comment: Your attitude is the same as mine.  I prefer to use auto migrations when possible, but dip down to raw SQL on occasion.